# File structure relative to sshd jail root

Tags: linux, bash, chroot, sshd, jail

I'm setting up an sshd jail for some users on my system (archlinux).  Without going into great detail I'd like to keep the scope of the question minimal.

Setting `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match group jaileduser
          ChrootDirectory /var/jailedusers
          X11Forwarding no
          AllowTcpForwarding no
```

and a system `/etc/password` entry similar to:

```
testuser1:x:2001:2000::/home/testuser1:/bin/bash
```

So the question is:  **Is the home directory of `/home/testuser1` relative to the `sshd_config` entry `/var/jailedusers`** i.e. should the passwd entry be **`/var/jailedusers/home/testuser1`** or **`/home/testuser1`** with a directory in `/var/jailedusers` of `/home/testuser1` - AND is the shell in the same boat - is the passwd entry **`/var/jailedusers/bin/bash`** or simply **`/bin/bash`**.

Lastly upon login is the system `/etc/passwd` read or is `/var/jailedusers/etc/passwd` read as per `sshd_config` entry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the manpage:

```
Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-
owned directories that are not writable by any other user or
group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory
to the user's home directory.
```

So `/etc/passwd` needs to contain the paths relative to the system's root (i.e. `/bin/bash` and `/home/testuser1`) and the system's root will, after chroot, actually be `/var/jailedusers` (meaning that `/var/jailedusers/home/testuser1` will be the actual home and `/var/jailedusers/bin/bash` the actual shell).

To answer the second part of the question, `sshd` will read `/etc/passwd`, perform authentication and then `chroot` to `/var/jailedusers`.

Note that `/var/jailedusers` will also need to contain additional files, such as the shared libraries required by `bash` and a minimal set of `/dev` entries (e.g. `/dev/null`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - understand much more now - lastly, do I have to have 'two' home directories? i.e. /home/testuser1 and /var/jailedusers/home/testuser1?

Comment: well, you will need two paths: one under `/home` and one under `/var/jailedusers/home`. But these could be the same directory if using `bind` mounts (see `mount` manpage). Alternatively, put jailed user's homes only under `/var/jailedusers/home`, updating `/etc/passwd` accordingly and symlink `/var/jailedusers /var/jailedusers/home` to `/var/jailedusers/home` (so that `/var/jailedusers/home` is a valid path before and after `chroot`).

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is - does it have to authenticate 'outside' of the chroot dir before switching to it?

Comment: `sshd` authenticates before it does a `chroot`... that's the way it is designed.

Comment: Thanks mate - that answers it perfect - it's hard to visualize it unless explained sometimes :)  Thanks again!

Comment: The reason I'm asking is I'm trying to execute a proprietary bash script - so the system passwd has /bin/bash but the chroot etc/passwd has /bin/menu - does that sound about right?

Comment: no need for chroot'd `/etc/passwd` unless the script wants to read it: `/etc/passwd` will be used by `sshd` only. So put `/bin/menu` in `/etc/passwd`, copy the `menu` script to `/var/jailedusers/bin/menu`, copy all the stuff `menu` needs under `/var/jailedusers` too and `sshd` will chroot then run `/bin/menu` in the jail.

Comment: One final question - it's showing /home/testuser1/menu as a directory 'Not a directory' is the error - I've checked everywhere for a trailing '/' but no matter what I do it won't execute the script - even double checked #!/usr/bin/bash in the script - befuddled.